# Merge key/value into response.data inline?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a simple question, but my lack of JavaScript skills is probably preventing me from figuring out a one-liner to do this. Im using axios to request from an API, im getting a response back (This is for a "Todo" list app), however I need to merge another field into this response.

The snippet of code looks like this:

```
        let mergedIsEditing = {...response.data, isEditing: false}
        const lists = [ ...this.state.lists, mergedIsEditing ]
```

`lists` is basically what it sounds like (an array of lists), and the `response.data` is nothing more than an object with a `title` and `description`. I thought maybe using `Object.assign` but since im already spreading out `this.state.lists` im not sure how that would work. Essentially I just need to add the key/value pair `isEditing: false` onto that list coming in.

Comment: Can you add an example of what your desired output would look like?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Given response.data is an object with title, description, mergedIsEditing ends up being `{title: 'some value', description: 'some value', isEditing: false}`. But you said lists should be a list of lists. What does each list contain of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to encourage shorter code over readability, but to answer your question, this is how you could do the equivalent to your snippet in 1 line:

```
let mergedIsEditing = {...response.data, isEditing: false}
const lists = [ ...this.state.lists, mergedIsEditing ]
```

```
const lists = [ ...this.state.lists, {...response.data, isEditing: false} ]
```

Of course, you could prepend `this.state.lists =`, if that's the desired purpose.

Comment: What do you mean prepend `this.state.lists =` By default there is nothing in it, it's just a blank array. Im having to add this key/value pair everytime a list is created by appending it onto the response.data (Which is simply a .json response of the created list (title and description))

Comment: I meant, you could replace `const lists = ...` with `this.state.lists = ...` *if* that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Ah gotcha! that makes sense.